# Playback multiple sounds starting in exactly the same moment

Tags: ios, xcode, nstimer, avaudioplayer

I need to playback short audio samples with precise timing, including up to 4 sounds starting simultaneously.
These sound samples are triggered with NSTimers (alternatively, I've also tried dispatch_after).

I've tried with AVPlayer and AVAudioPlayer but they are just not precise enough in timing.
Multiple sounds played at once will be all over the place, especially on the real device.

I've read about NSTimer allowing up to a few 100 milliseconds deviation, which is just too much for me.

As a test I've setup a few AVAudioPlayers with one audio sample each and triggered them all at the same time in didSelectRow...() but they will not sound in exactly the same moment, even with no NSTimer involved.
It seems that it's just not possible to playback 2 sounds starting exactly at the same time with AVAudioPlayer. Is this confirmed?

From what I've gathered there are not many alternatives, Audio Queue Service being one that allows precise timing and multiple sounds at once.
However, it's written in C, which I've never worked with, and it is hard to find any examples showing how to integrate this for simple audio playback of a sound (I'm using Swift). I'd basically just need to know how to integrate Audio Queue Services to playback a simple sound.

If someone can point me in the right direction (or knows a better solution to what I'm looking for), that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Using `AVAudioEngine` with `AVAudioPlayerNode` (not `AVAudioPlayer`) this should definitely be possible. You have control over timing etc. However, it's more complex.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Arthur! I did not look into AVAudioPlayerNode yet. I will do and will report back once I've tested it.

Comment: Arthur, I've had a look into AVAudioPlayerNode but have a feeling that it does far more than I'm asking for and is, as you've said, more complex. While trying around I've found that AVAudioPlayer's play(atTime:) actually does what I'm trying to achieve. If you post this as the answer here I will accept it. The problem is setting the playback up for what I'm looking for. I've posted a follow-up question with a working code sample here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764951/precise-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer-playattime thx a lot!